# Refresh element modified in Adapter RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Hello I have a problem with `RecyclerView`. 
I have a `RecyclerView` with row layout and `interface` with my activity for click on button and make a request to db for update name.

I have in my **row_layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name" 

                     />
    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/change_name"
       android:text="@string/change"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And I have my Adapter that when click on Button should change name on DB and on holder.

**Adapter**

```
    public class ListAlertsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAlertsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
     private JSONArray dataSource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;
        public  interface AdapterCallback {

            void handleName(View caller, JSONObject obj, JSONArray data, int position);

        }
    public ListAlertsAdapter(JSONArray dataArgs, Context context){
            dataSource = dataArgs;
            inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.mAdapterCallback = ((AdapterCallback) context);
        }
      @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row,parent,false);
            MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view, new ListAlertsAdapter.MyViewHolder.IMyViewHolderClicks() {

                public void handleName(View caller, int position) {
                    JSONObject itemClicked;
                    try {
                        itemClicked = dataSource.getJSONObject(position);
                        mAdapterCallback.handleName(caller, itemClicked, dataSource, position);
                       /** maybe in this point i could modify itemClicked and notifyDataSetChanged() but not working */

                itemClicked.put("name","exampleName Marco");
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            return holder;
        }
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       try {
                object = dataSource.getJSONObject(position);
                holder.name.setText(object.getString("name"));
       }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
Button handle_name;
public IMyViewHolderClicks mListener;
public MyViewHolder(View itemView, IMyViewHolderClicks listener) {
  super(itemView);
            mListener = listener;
     handle_name=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.change_name);
            handle_name.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         mListener.handleName(v, position);
       }
}
public interface IMyViewHolderClicks {
     public void handleName(View caller, int position);
}
```

So when I click on my button i call a function in **my Activity**  Like this

```
public void handleName(View caller, final JSONObject obj, JSONArray data, int position) {
   SystemService.getInstance().handleName("example name");
}
```

that make a volleyrequest and update name in db with example "Marco" and so my questions is, How can hide button that i clicked and set name in realtime after call db?
sorry for so much code! thankyou all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create list with visibility of each button in adapter. After you click on button, change visibility of button in clicked position to `View.GONE` and then refresh your adapter.